# Why does it do this ? if - __name__ == '__main__'

Tags: python

> **Duplicate of:**
>   [What does `if __name__== "__main__"` do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)

Consider this code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import pdb
    pdb.run("interact()\n")
```

What does the following line mean?

```
if(__name__=='__main__')
```

I fainted.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This will be true if this module is being run as a standalone program. That way, something can act either as a module imported by another program, or a standalone program, but only execute the code in the `if` statement if executed as a program.

Answer (score 14):

`__name__` is a variable automatically set in an executing python program. If you `import` your module from another program, `__name__` will be set to the name of the module. If you run your program directly, `__name__` will be set to `__main__`.

Therefore, if you want some things to happen *only* if you're running your program from the command line and not when imported (eg. unit tests for a library), you can use the

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
  # will run only if module directly run
  print "I am being run directly"
else:
  # will run only if module imported
  print "I am being imported"
```

trick. It's a common Python idiom.

Answer (score 4):

That is a check to see if you are directly running the script or if it is included in a library.

When you run a python script like this:

```
python myScript.py
```

It sends a parameter, telling you to run the programs first method, which is widely called "main", so when `__name__` is `__main__` you know that the program was executed from a command line or double clicked.

Answer (score 1):

He has written a python module, intended to be used via `import`.

If the module is passed to the interpreter as the main python script, the code you quote will run.  This will invoke the `interact()` method under the python debugger.